# how to set regular validation expression dynamically in codebehind C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have `RegularExpressionValidator` in `ascx` page that validates `TextBox1`.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID ="RegularExpressionValidatorStateNumber" runat = "server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
ErrorMessage="Error message" Display ="Dynamic" ValidationExpression=""/>
```

I need to change `ValidationExpression` dynamically depending on choice of`dropdownlist`.

Here what I do in codeBehind:

```
protected void DropDlSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    string region = DropDl.SelectedItem.Text;            
    RegularExpressionValidatorStateNumber.ValidationExpression = GetRegex(region); 
}
```

Function `GetRegex(region)` that returns regex expression works fine.
But validation not works. Validator doesn't show error message when wrong data inserted.

*Why validation not works? Or how to set validation expression dynamically?*

Answer (score 1):

Show your error message not as *ErrorMessage*, but as *Text*.
*Text="Not correct format"*;

Also it would be good if you will color it: *ForeColor = Color.Red*

Answer (score 0):

Use `MATCH` which returns a Match object with all matches in the input string. This is useful when more than one match exists in the input text. The following code results in more than one match:

```
 string region = DropDl.SelectedItem.Text; // @"^([\w]+) ([\w]+)$";
 string yourText="abcdxyz"

Match m = Regex.Match(yourText, region , RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
}
```

Comment: Regex part of my problem works fine. My `RegularExpressionValidator` doesn't show error message.

Answer (score 0):

ex0: 10 Digit mobile number
rgvMobNumber.ValidationExpression = "\d{" + iLength + "}";

ex1: 
rgvPostcode.ValidationExpression = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{" + txtboxLength + ",8}$";
ex2
rgvPostcode.ValidationExpression =@"^[\s\S]{" + MinLength + "," + MaxLength + "}$";